# Wixtoolset: change focus in SelectionTree

Tags: wix

My installer has several features. I need to programmatically change focus by condition (select a specific feature). Is there such a possibility, if there is any direction in which to look for information on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident there is no such thing in the Windows Installer. Wix would expose it if it were possible. As I understand it, the Feature Tree control in the Windows Installer is not very accessiblity-friendly either.

Fundamentally, it is a very old UI control that provides very little control over it.